# Lenovo Z500. Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

Recently I have been facing 2 issues with my laptop(Lenovo Z500) :

1. The screen turns pink/purple automatically and turns normal again automatically.

[image: Pink Screen]

2. Arrow keys (mostly left arrow key) gets pressed automatically.

Comment: A test with external monitor and keyboard would isolate some internal signal issues from others. Can you do this?  Any spills lately?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issues i followed the following steps now i face no such issue.

First i updated all my drivers and firmware to the latest. this temperorily solved my problem( for one month) then i dont know what went wrong, i faced the same issues again.

Now i went to the lenovo website where i found the beta drivers. i downloaded and used them this solved the arrow key problem.

For screen issue i downloaded video driver from beta softwares changed the system details with win 8 details and installed the drivers now screen is perfect.

If you dont want to do all these you can simply change the drivers to microsoft driver in device manager. but it will affect sys performance.